# Return an array of numbers from an return method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want a return type method for reading numbers from keyboard. So i create this method. but it doesn't return anything. what is the problem in my code?

```
int num [] = new int[10];
public int  read()
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

        for(i=0;i<num.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number "+i);
            num[i] = s.nextInt();   
        }

        return num;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return an array, change the return type to `int[]`.
It would also be better to create the array inside the method, since you probably don't want the same array object to be returned in consecutive calls.

```
public int[] read()
{
    int num [] = new int[10];
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    for(i=0;i<num.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number "+i);
        num[i] = s.nextInt();   
    }

    return num;
}
```